# Erro função setsid relativo ao ppid

Tags: c

****Ao executar o fonte abaixo relativo a criação de um deamon com a função setsid, foi verificado que após o comando ps -fu root, o ppid não é 1, ou seja o mesmo do init do sistema operacional. O fonte foi retirado do livro Programando em C para Linux, Unix e Windows, com finalidade didática. Já tentei todo o tipo de modificação no fonte e não consigo com que o líder do processo tenha o mesmo ppid do init. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda e desde já agradeço. Meu sistema operacional é o buntu 14.04.****

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int daemon_init (void)
{
pid_t iPid/*,sid*/;
long iMaxFd;
int i;

if ((iPid = fork()) < 0)
return -1;//exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
if (iPid != 0)
exit(0);//exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
setsid();//sid=setsid()
chdir ("/");
umask (0);
iMaxFd = sysconf (_SC_OPEN_MAX);
for (i=0; i < iMaxFd; i++)
close (i);
return 0;
}
void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int iFd;
char szBuffer[100];
int i;
if (daemon_init () < 0)
{
perror (argv[0]);
exit (errno);
}
sprintf (szBuffer, "/tmp/daemon%d.arq", getpid());//cria buffer .arq
iFd = open (szBuffer, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0700);//cria arquivo
i = 1;
while (1)
{
sleep(3);
sprintf(szBuffer, "Esta eh a linha de numero %04d\n", i++);
write(iFd, szBuffer, strlen(szBuffer));
}
exit (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está rodando seu programa em um desktop gráfico (GNOME, KDE, etc). Testei no GNOME e realmente acontece como você disse.

Se você rodar em console (CTRL+ALT+Fn) o parent pid do daemon vai ser 1 (processo init).

Comment: Não entendi seu comentário. Estou executado o programa diretamente no terminal com o comando ./exec, no caso, exec é meu arquivo executável para a função que contém o deamon.

Comment: Você está rodando o terminal em algum ambiente gráfico, como GNOME ou KDE ? Se estiver, é a isso que se refere minha resposta. Se não estive então não sei explicar. Reproduzi o comportamento que você descreveu rodando o programa no gnome-terminal. Na console nativa do Linux funcionou como esperado.

Comment: Agora entendi. O detalhe e como rodar na console nativa do buntu. Nesse caso teria que ser através de um sistema linux sem interface gráfica??

Comment: Pra rodar na console nativa eu já coloquei na minha resposta, você usa as teclas CTRL+ALT+F1, ou CTRL+ALT+F2, etc...pra abrir uma console, Se não me engano o desktop gráfico roda no CTRL+ALT+F6 ou CTRL+ALT+F7, então começa no CTRL+ALT+F1 e vai testando. Pra voltar pro desktop gráfico você usa CTRL+ALT+F6 ou CTRL+ALT+F7. Não tenho muita certeza porque não uso mais Ubuntu, uso Fedora,

Comment: Valeu pela dica. Vou tentar e dou retorno.

Comment: Meu caro você está completamente, totalmente, inteiramente certo. Só não entendi por que só funciona no console nativo.

Comment: O que se pode inferir é que um dos processos do desktop gráfico é o ancestral de todos os processos criados no desktop, portanto um processo que normalmente seria herdado pelo processo 1 (init) é herdado por algum processo de controle de desktop gráfico.

Comment: Se esta resposta doi útil para você marque como aceita, por favor.